# How to use !isNan in Jquery function of Calculate-sum-of-value in Columns and Rows html table

Tags: jquery

I have a table some columns are with text string and some of columns are with number. When do the sum calculation, the sum results display many NaN.  How can I get ride of these NaN. I do not want to sum up Text string and Serial number.
I have tried may ways with !isNan && condition but could not figured out the solution.

```
  <table class="table" id="table">
  <thead>
  <tr>
  {{!-- <th>Table SN</th> --}}
  <th>Transact_SN</th>  
  <th>Customer_Name</th>
  <th>Ticket_Amount$</th>
  <th>Bank_Fee</th> 
  <th>Phone_Fee</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
   <td>11000</td>
   <td>John</td>
   <td>1000</td>
   <td>100</td>
   <td>10</td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>12000</td>
   <td>Mike</td>
   <td>1500</td>
   <td>500</td>
   <td>20</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
   var result = [];
   $('table tr').each(function(){
   $('td', this).each(function(index, val){
    if(!result[index]) result[index] = 0;
    result[index] += parseInt($(val).text());
    });
   });

    $('table').append('<tr></tr>');
    $(result).each(function(){
    $('table tr').last().append('<td>'+this+'</td>')
    });
   });
    
  </script>
```

Comment: I've updated my answer below, please take a look again.

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore the NaN using below JS.

```js
if(!result[index]) result[index] = 0;
    var number = parseInt($(val).text()) || 0;
    result[index] += number;
});
```

When you want to ignore few columns from being consider, you should try something like below.

```js
$('table tr td:nth-child(3), table tr td:nth-child(4), table tr td:nth-child(5)').each(function(index, value){

    // your code below like you have.
    if(!result[index]) result[index] = 0;
    result[index] += parseInt($(val).text());
});
```

---

`$('table tr td:nth-child(3), table tr td:nth-child(4), table tr td:nth-child(5)')`
This will give you td row wise, not column wise. TD from first row will be first in the list.

---

---

***Here is the snippet that gives you exact solution.***

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var result = [];

    $('table tr').each(function(){
     $('td', this).each(function(index, val){
      if(!result[index]) result[index] = 0;
      result[index] += (parseInt($(val).text()) || 0);
      });
     });


    $('table').append('<tr></tr>');
    $(result).each(function(){
      $('table tr').last().append('<td><strong>'+this+'</strong></td>')
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="table">
  <thead>
  <tr>
  <th>Transact_SN</th>  
  <th>Customer_Name</th>
  <th>Ticket_Amount$</th>
  <th>Bank_Fee</th> 
  <th>Phone_Fee</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
   <td>11000</td>
   <td>John</td>
   <td>1000</td>
   <td>100</td>
   <td>10</td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>12000</td>
   <td>Mike</td>
   <td>1500</td>
   <td>500</td>
   <td>20</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: Nice solution,
 I am just not familiar with Table child methods, so I tried may times and could not get it right. Your way is a good way for my problem. Thank you Mr.Hiren Bhalani.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is taking it to the extreme, but the whole thing can be done in a single line:

```js
$(function(){
  $("#table tbody").append('<tr class="sums"><td>'+["Totals:",0,1,1,1].map((s,i)=>s===1?$('#table tbody tr td:nth-child('+(i+1)+')').get().reduce((a,c)=>+c.textContent+a,0):(s===0?$('#table tbody tr').length+' rows':s)).join("</td><td>")+"</td></tr>");
});
```

```css
.sums td {font-weight:900}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="table">
  <thead>
  <tr>
  <th>Transact_SN</th>  
  <th>Customer_Name</th>
  <th>Ticket_Amount$</th>
  <th>Bank_Fee</th> 
  <th>Phone_Fee</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
   <td>11000</td>
   <td>John</td>
   <td>1000</td>
   <td>100</td>
   <td>10</td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>12000</td>
   <td>Mike</td>
   <td>1500</td>
   <td>500</td>
   <td>20</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
```

The "control array" `["Totals:","-",1,1,1]` governs which column is to be summed up. This is necessary because we cannot tell simply from the type of `<td>`-content whether a column should be summed up or not. If the control array value `s` is `===1` the summation will take place for the `(i+1)`-th column within the jQuery-`.map()` call, otherwise the value `s` will be shown in the summation row. The summation itself is done via a `.reduce()`-call acting on an array of all the `<td>`s of a summation column. The array with all sums (or blanks, in case of a "no-sum-column") is then `.join()`-ed into a table row and `.append()`-ed to the table.

Comment: Great idea.   Solved my problem by  two steps , Treat them separately and join them at final step. 
Thank you Mr. Carsten Massmann

Comment: Use "-" replaced 0 and Use font - weight:900  That made my table SUM  have very good look. Thanks.  and the Transact_SN column have row count 3  it mean 3 Total rows. right ?

Comment: Well, if you want you can of course return a row count (we have 2 rows here, not 3) in one of the no-sum columns. See my latest update.

Comment: Now, That column has number 3 in front of Totals.  So the display is like: 
  3Totals   2500  600  30

Comment: reduce((a,c)=>a+=+c. is same as 
const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue; right ?

Comment: My version uses the unary operator `+` to force a numeric type conversion for `c`. That would.be missing in your version.

Comment: . I need polish my Jquery skill. Thanks

Comment: And don't forget: I am also getting the `textContent` of `c`. So I could also simplify my "reducer-code" further to `+c.textContent+a`, see my updated post.

Comment: Well, actually, most of  it is JavaScript, not jQuery. ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233308/discussion-between-jason-and-carsten-massmann).